# Jquery striped rows

Tags: jquery

Ive got this script:

```
$(function(){

  $(".submenu li:even").addClass("oddrow");

});
```

It works great - but it continues to stripe through all the submenus...

How do i contain it, so it starts again at the start of each submenu

Comment: what do you mean it starts again at the start of each submenu, an example?

Comment: And what's your HTML mark-up?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how come you add the class `oddrow` to your even rows?

Comment: @XepterX i think that he means that he has various ul on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a  [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) to restrict the selection  (i imagine you have various `<ul>` that contains your `<li>`) so that you iterate over the `<ul>` and then select only the even `<li>` of that `<ul>`

```
$(function(){
   $(".submenu ul").each(function(){
       //provide a context so that it select only `<li>` that are 
       //descendant of that `<ul>` `this` is the current `<ul>`
       $("li:even", this).addClass("oddrow");
   });
});
```